# convert text-string of hours + mins to rounded decimal hours in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have a text-string `1 hour 43 mins`

How can I convert this to output `1.75` using PHP?

*(and this be true for all other possibilities, rounding to nearest .25 hours)*

Comment: This seems like an assignment. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You take the hours, store it in a variable called hours. Take the minutes, device them by 60, and do a simple addition.

Take care of the case where minutes = 0, because it will throw an exception since you cannot divide by 0